# NoMethodError undefined method `link_to_function'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, will-paginate

I added ActiveAdmin to my app, updated some gems and now I get a `` undefined method `link_to_function' `` when viewing users show page. I have the `will_paginate` gem and I added a initializer so there's no conflict.

kaminari.rb:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

The error points to the line on from /app/helpers/will_paginate_helper.rb:

```
  @template.link_to_function(text.to_s.html_safe, ajax_call, attributes)
```

Comment: both pagination gems together ??

Comment: `link_to_function` method is deprecated in Rails 4.1.x.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a helper method and it will fix your problem.

link_to_function_helper.rb:

```
module LinkToFunctionHelper
  def link_to_function(name, *args, &block)
     html_options = args.extract_options!.symbolize_keys

     function = block_given? ? update_page(&block) : args[0] || ''
     onclick = "#{"#{html_options[:onclick]}; " if html_options[:onclick]}#{function}; return false;"
     href = html_options[:href] || '#'

     content_tag(:a, name, html_options.merge(:href => href, :onclick => onclick))
  end
end
```