# Implementing read more read less functionality in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working with active admin gem.

I wanted to implement read more functionality in my description.

I tried the following code.

It is working and hiding characters after 250.

When we click on read more it is not displaying

```
<div>
  <% if @category_name.summary.length > 250 %>
    <%= truncate(@category_name.summary, length: 250) %>
    <%= link_to '...Read more', '', class: "header_section-#{(@category_name.summary)}" %>
    <script>
      $('.read-more-<%= @category_name.summary%>').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).parent().html('<%= escape_javascript @category_name.summary %>')
      })
    </script>
  <% else %>
    <%= @category_name.summary %>
  <% end %>
<div>
```

Comment: How can we identify  the problem on the basis of **I am working with active admin gem here is my code**

Comment: i wanted to implement  read more functionality in my description for which i tried the following code it is working and hidding characters after 250 but when we click on read more it is not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this

```
<div>
   <% if @category_name.summary.length > 250 %>
    <%= link_to_function truncate(@category_name.summary, length: 250), "$(this).parent().html('#{escape_javascript @category_name.summary}')" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= @category_name.summary %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

For the **Read more** link

```
<div>
  <% if @category_name.summary.length > 250 %>
    <%= truncate( @category_name.summary, length: 250) %>
    <%= link_to_function '...Read more', "$(this).parent().html('#{escape_javascript  @category_name.summary}')" %>
  <% else %>
    <%=  @category_name.summary %>
  <% end %>
<div>
```

**Note**: Add a helper method

```
link_to_function_helper.rb
```

Comment: i have tried the above code but it is showing undefined method link to function

Comment: @JithinR Add a helper method and it will fix your problem. go through https://stackoverflow.com/a/26238640/5830036

Comment: thanks it is working  but the page is getting displayed as this  <p><strong>You&rsquo;ve probably already used many of the applications that were built with Ruby on Rails:</strong> <a href="https://basecamp.com">Basecamp</a>, <a href="https://github.com">GitHub</a>, <a href="https://shopify.com">Shopify</a>, <a...

Comment: its not readable

Comment: @JithinR Try again using `.html_safe` like `<%=@category_name.summary.html_safe%>` or `<%=raw @category_name.summary %>`

Comment: i tried the same but still it is not working

Comment: @JithinR Post output here in readable format

Comment: @JithinR  try to add `to_s` `<%=@category_name.summary.to_s.html_safe%>`

Comment: output is coming like this   ..

Comment: <p><strong>You&rsquo;ve probably already used many of the applications that were built with Ruby on Rails:</strong>    ... even though the click funstion is now working

Comment: Try to replace all `@category_name`  with `@category_name.summary.to_s.html_safe`

Comment: hi thanks for the help but i have used the method but does not seem to work it is still showing the same format

Comment: @JithinR I didn't find any other problem in your code.

Comment: dont know what is happening all html tags and attricutes are getting displayed

Comment: one thing i forgot to tell was that we are using CK editor for this project

Comment: @JithinR  Do it one thing, Your problem was solved as per above question so close this question and ask a new question with all relevant codes and descriptions this will helps you more. and don't forget to vote up and mark as correct this answer

Comment: iam new to stack not able to vote your comment

Comment: @JithinR not an issue,do it after you able.